# bash script check if file exist and sent an information email

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp

I worte a simple script to check if there are some files exist (endded with .txt) in the dirctoey older than 6 hours, after the check to send an email.
The scripte isnt working well and as expected,  I ask you if there's some simpler and more powerful way to do it? Basically it just needs to check if file eneded with .txt exists and older than 6hours, if yes an email should be sent.

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M`
HOSTNAME='host'
BASEDIR=`/usr/local/se/work/jobs/`
LOGFILE=`/usr/local/se/work/jobs/logs/jobs.log`
VERTEILER="anyemail"
# Functions
#
# function check if the jobs are exists

'find ${BASEDIR} -name "*.txt" -nmin +354' 2>$1 >>$LOGFILE

#function mail
cat << EOF | mailx -s "Example ${HOSTNAME} jobs `date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M`" -a ${LOGFILE} ${VERTEILER}

Hi,

Please check the Jobs.

Details :

`ls -ltr /usr/local/se/work/jobs/`

------------      END       ----------------------------------------
.
Thank you
```

Comment: EOF is not End-Of-File but a marker that you need to put on a line after `Thank you`. Please replace backtics with `$(ls -ltr something)`, what is the preferred way to call a subprocess. Remove the single quotes with find.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try to run this script?

The grave accent (`) in `BASEDIR` and `LOGFILE` means the shell will try to evaluate them as commands which fails. You don't generally need quotes around strings in shell scripts, although it may be considered good practice to use double quotes (").

```
HOSTNAME=host
BASEDIR=/usr/local/se/work/jobs
LOGFILE=${LOGFILE}/logs/jobs.log
VERTEILER=anyemail
```

The switch to search files by minutes in called `mmin` and not `nmin` -- again that should have given you an error. And the math is wrong, if you want 6 hours then it's 6 * 60 = 360 minutes.

```
find ${BASEDIR} -name *.txt -mmin +360
```

You are redirecting stderr to the first input parameter. (`2>$1`) Are you expecting error output from this command, could you explain what is going on here?

And then you append that to `LOGFILE` which is in a directory that may not exist. `mkdir -p` is a good choice for creating folders in scripts because it creates parent directories when needed and won't complain if the folder already exists. So do something along the lines of

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/se/work/jobs/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` use `2>&1`, you are doing it wrong with `2>$1`

Also, the correct parameter for find is `-mmin` not `-nmin` like you have in your code.

Further more you have syntax errors like here:

```
BASEDIR=`/usr/local/se/work/jobs/`
LOGFILE=`/usr/local/se/work/jobs/logs/jobs.log`
```

What you mean to type is:

```
BASEDIR='/usr/local/se/work/jobs/'
LOGFILE='/usr/local/se/work/jobs/logs/jobs.log'
```

When you use `backticks` `bash` tries to execute `COMMAND`, you are using it the right way here:

```
DATE=`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M`
```

You are also not closing the heredoc `<<EOF`, you need `EOF` on the last line of the script.

And lose the `''` surrounding the `find` command.

You should pay attention to what bash says, it should prompt lots of errors, try to run the script manually to see them if you are using this via `cron`.